# Laravel - Unable to acces relationship

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I have this piece of code `$mypost = Post::with('options', 'content')->where('id', '=', $id)->get();`
It retrieves the desired post perfectly.

What i want is to be able to access it's relationships, so in this case `options` and `content`.

But when I do this: `dd($mypost->content);` it throws an error.

> Property [content] does not exist on this collection instance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since you're doing `->get();` at the end you get a collection. If you wish to simply retrieve 1 post you can use `->find($postId);` instead. `$mypost = Post::with('options', 'content')->find($id);`

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `get`, you're getting a Collection of objects, not a single object. You want to use `first()` to get a single object.

```
$mypost = Post::with('options', 'content')->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I overlooked that.

Comment: Quick follow up question, how would I implement this in a foreach so i'm able to do this for all posts?

Comment: Where would this be in relation to a foreach?

Comment: Well for every post I want to put ```$mypost->content``` in an array.

Comment: You should be able to do that easily. It just depends on how your code is structured.